# Удаление директории средствами WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

Пишу деинсталлятор... При запуске он копирует себя во временную папку, передавая в качестве аргумента командной строки директорию запуска своего первого экземпляра, и из Temp по этой директории удаляет все файлы и папки... кроме одной - директории запуска своего приложения-родителя, при этом самого родителя успешно затирает при помощи DeleteFile(). Корневую папку отказывается удалять с кодом 32 (приложение занято другим процессом).

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить эту последнюю директорию?
Наверное надо как-то обеспечить независимость запускаемого экземпляра от приложения родителя, или как-то запускать дочернее приложение с задержкой, при этом, чтобы успел закрыться вызывающий процесс... Только я не знаю как эти догадки реализовать... ((

Comment: Ну, пусть удалятор подождёт, пока родительский процесс завершится. У него же есть на него хендл. И только после этого пусть удаляет.

Comment: Так приложение-родитель удаляется потомком успешно, не понятно какая там взаимосвязь остаётся. Тем более, что количество удаляемых файлов и папок около 500, то есть пара секунд на закрытие точно есть...

Comment: Хм, тогда опишите лучше то, что у вас происходит. Условно, у вас есть в `Program Files` `Prog\Prog.exe` и `Prog\Uninst.exe`, вы запускаете `Uninst.exe`, который копирует себя в `%Temp%` и запускает себя там. Та копия пытается удалить каталог `Prog`, верно?

Comment: Абсолютно верно. В каталоге Prog есть файлы и каталоги других прог, которые нормально удаляются. Также успешно удаляется корневая директория со всем содержимым в %APPDATA%\Prog. А вот сам Prog, откуда был создан и вызван из %TEMP%-а дубликат Uninst, отвечает на удаление 32-м кодом ошибки

Comment: а! у меня есть идея :) а попробуйте поменять у Uninst.exe текущий каталог

Comment: То есть? Из %TEMP% ещё куда-то его деть? Или в ТЕМП создать ещё один дубликат? Или Вы имеете ввиду не дублировать деинсталлятор, а перенести его?

Comment: не-не, у него ж есть текущий каталог

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: он наверное указывает на `Prog`.

Comment: перенести вы не сможете, пока `Prog\Uninst.exe` работает

Comment: `MoveFileEx` с флагом `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT`, нет? Удалится после перезагрузки.

Comment: Тааак... Теперь вопрос: а как Вам поднять карму на +100500 за идею со сменой директории (SetCurrentDirectory)??? )))

Comment: Сработало? Вот и хорошо. Тогда напишу ответ, поставьте зелёную галочку :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что каталог нельзя удалить потому, что он является текущим каталогом в удаляющем процессе.

Попробуйте сменить текущий каталог при помощи [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx).